# BASH array variable name concatenating

Tags: arrays, bash, concatenation

I’ve got a little problem with the variable **name** concatenation oder replacement in BASH. Given is:

```
#!/bin/bash
Audio1=(0:ita, 96k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000)   # audio stream definitions
Audio2=(1:rus, 128k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000)  # for use in ffmpeg or
Audio3=(2:klg, 96k, AAC, 1.0, s16le, 48000)   # avconv
# and so on, now processing the audio streams
for ((i=1 ; i<=8 ; i++)) ; do
  Audio="Audio$i"
  Audio=${!Audio}
  if [ ${#Audio[0]} -gt 0 ] ; then
    # do the job with $Audio, here examplaryly:
    echo ${Audio[@]}
  fi
done
```

Expected as result was:

```
0:ita, 96k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000
1:rus, 128k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000
2:klg, 96k, AAC, 1.0, s16le, 48000
```

I got:

```
0:ita,
1:rus,
2:klg,
```

It’s only half the solution, because there is only the first element copied of each source array instead of been totally copied into the working array $Audio. In PHP I would write the variable name replacement simply by:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) {
  $Audio = ${'Audio'.$i};     // ← that’s all the magic in PHP ;-)
  if (isset($Audio[0])) {
    // blabla
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I can’t use PHP for this application. Of course, this is one of my first scripts in BASH. Switching over to any other coding (e.g. many simple variables instead of few arrays) aren’t an option. I have to use these presets. So, where’s my fault, what’s going wrong?

Greetings - Bert

Comment: Array elements are separated by whitespace, not commas.

Comment: Thanks. I feel, that will be not the last mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BASH versions 4.3+ you can use `declare -n`:

```
for ((i=1 ; i<=3; i++)) ; do
   declare -n Audio="Audio$i"
   if [[ ${#Audio[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
       echo "${Audio[@]}"
   fi
done

0:ita, 96k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000
1:rus, 128k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000
2:klg, 96k, AAC, 1.0, s16le, 48000
```

`-n` makes `NAME` a reference to the variable named by its `value`. So in above code `Audio` is a reference to the value contained in `Audio1`, `Audio2`, `Audio3` etc.

Comment: Thanks, anubhava! I think, it’s the best solution. I read many explanations about the variable name manipulation, but this item "declare" I have jumped over everytime. It seemed not to be the right thing.

Comment: `-n` makes `NAME` a reference to the variable named by its `value`. So in above code `Audio` is a reference to the value contained in `$Audio`

Comment: Thanks @chepner, yes indeed it is 4.3+

Comment: @Bert, if you have the right bash version, `declare -n` is exactly what you want.

Comment: bash says:GNU bash, Version 4.3.30(1)-release-(i586-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1):

Without using namerefs, you can do:

```
Audio1=(0:ita, 96k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000)   # audio stream definitions
Audio2=(1:rus, 128k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000)  # for use in ffmpeg or
Audio3=(2:klg, 96k, AAC, 1.0, s16le, 48000)   # avconv

for i in {1..3}; do
    aryvar="Audio${i}[@]"   # this is the special magic indirect varname
    for value in "${!aryvar}"; do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "$value"; done
    # ...........^^^^^^^^^^^^ expands to elements of the array
done
```

outputs

```
1   0:ita,
1   96k,
1   AAC,
1   2.0,
1   s16le,
1   48000
2   1:rus,
2   128k,
2   AAC,
2   2.0,
2   s16le,
2   48000
3   2:klg,
3   96k,
3   AAC,
3   1.0,
3   s16le,
3   48000
```

---

I missed your desired output. Here it is:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do
    aryvar="Audio${i}[*]"    # note the "*" not "@"
    echo "${!aryvar}"
done
0:ita, 96k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000
1:rus, 128k, AAC, 2.0, s16le, 48000
2:klg, 96k, AAC, 1.0, s16le, 48000
```

Comment: Thank you, Glenn, too. It isn’t exactly the wanted output, but for later possibly using of simple parts of my arrays I’m going to remind your solution in the back of my mind.

Comment: Read about [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash manual (skip down a couple of paragraphs)